# Graph data structure terms

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

What is the difference between the terms `edge` and `path` in graph data structure?

Answer (score 3):

An edge is something that connects two nodes. A path is a series of edges in sequence that defines a "path" from node A to node B.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(data_structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29)

Answer (score 0):

Edge: connects node one node to another. So there no nodes present between node A and B. 
 eg. A<-->B or A-->B or A<---B.

Path: Connects 1 or more nodes to each other. So path contains 1 or more edges.
 eg. 1.) A---B---C : here path is ABC

```
2.) 
 A
/ \
```

B   C
   /
   D

Here different paths are A-B-C and A-C.
     Different edges are: A-B, B-C, A-C.

I hope this clears your doubt

Answer (score 0):

Edge is a connection between two vertices of the graph.

```
Consider the graph        a    b  
                        6---4----5
                            |    | \ e
                          c |   d|  1
                            |    | / f
                            3----2
                              g
```

a,b,c,d,e represents the edges of the graphs where as a path can be path from a to g that can be a,b,d,g or a,c,g.

Answer (score 0):

Edge is a point/dot ( maybe starting point, mid point, ending point).

Path is a line( sequence of point/dot makes a line).

Answer (score 0):

A graph is two tuple **G = (V, E)**, where:

> V -> set of vertices (points/nodes or whatever you call it)
>
> E -> set of **edges** (a line which connects any two vertices)

Such that: **(v,u)** belongs to **E** (set of edges) => **v**, **u** belongs to **V** (set of vertices).

Now, when we talk about **paths**: These are series of connected edges, which starts from a vertex and ends in another vertex.

Then you have several types of graphs : *i.e.* Connected/disconnected directed/undirected weighted/unweighted graphs.

Further reading : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

An edge connects two nodes and path is sequence of nodes and edges.